# How to match values of a Textbox to values stores in a text file

Tags: c#

Hi Guys I'm creating a log in system which has user accounts stored onto a text file. When a user enter their Username and password the program should check with the text file if the user exits, if not it should not grant access to the system

I have tried using StreamReader to Access the Path file to match the values but no avail

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

String user = usernameText.Text;
String pass = passText.Text;

StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"profiles.txt");

 if(user.Contains(File.ReadLines(@"profiles.txt").ToString()) && pass.Contains(File.ReadLines(@"profiles.txt").ToString()))
  {
      login.Show();
  }
  else
  {
       MessageBox.Show("The username or Password is Incorrect"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: what value stored inside text file?. @Calculus Student

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan The values stored in the text file Are the Users "Usernames and Passwords"

Comment: Why don't you just create maybe a `User` class, with username and password as properties. Then create a `List<User>`. You can then use Json to store the data, retrieve and use as needed. That should be a bit cleaner than using plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

Although you declared a `StreamReader` variable, you never used it. You opted for the `File.ReadLines()` static method instead. However, you are checking whether the user and password strings both contain all the lines in the file: `user.Contains(File.ReadLines(@"profiles.txt").ToString())`. Moreover, calling `ToString()` does not return the lines in the file, but rather the string representation of the `IEnumerable` *object* returned by `File.ReadLines()`.

In order to suggest another approach, I'll assume the following: each line of the file corresponds to a user and a password, there cannot be more than one user with the same username and password, a `User` class has been built as suggested by **bolkay** in the comments.

```
User user = null;
string line;
while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Contains(user) && line.Contains(password))
   {
      login.Show();
      user = new User() { Username = user, Password = password };
      break;
   }
}
if (user == null) MessageBox.Show("The username or Password is Incorrect");
```

If you want to use `File.ReadLines()`, then use a foreach instead of the while:
`foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("...")) { ... }`.